# Syntax Tree in Java - CDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm implementing an Eclipse Plugin for C programmers. I need to access the Syntax Tree, (the plug-in will visit the syntax tree to do its work). to do that I need to use IASTNode interface(correct me if I'm wrong), so I added the right packages to the plugin dependencies. Now when the user will highlight a variable I need to access the Syntax Tree to search this variable and its appearances in the code.

How can I achieve that ? (to generate the syntax tree and search in it for some information). 
(my Problem is that I can't find a way to generate the syntax tree for the C code).
Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15548938/2670892

Answer (score 0):

Test cases can always provide excellent code examples on how to use an api. As a starting point, please see: 
https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/master/core%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.core.tests%2Fparser%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcdt%2Fcore%2Fparser%2Ftests%2Fast2%2FAST2TestBase.java#L193